# Show week content only SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, week-number

i have a database with a Row named date and a type of Timestamp.
Now i have a problem with only viewing content where it is added in the current week. So that you don't see content of last week.
How can i do this in a query?, btw i am using MySQL

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Such functionality is too often product specific.)

Comment: Sorry, added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're happy with MySQL's [definition of week](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week):

```
where('WEEKOFYEAR(DATE(`date`)) = WEEKOFYEAR(NOW())');
```